# Turning by $\theta$ degrees each turn and travelling some $d$ distance each time. How many turns to get back to starting point?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose someone starts at a point A, and walks towards the North direction for some distance $d$. Then turns right $\theta$ degrees, and repeats the process. How many turns will he make until he reaches the starting point?

From what I've seen in problems, you calculate the external angle of turning i.e $180-\theta$. Then calculate $n$ for $$(180-\theta)n \equiv 0 \mod 360$$

However I can't quite make sense of this in my head. Please help me understand the intuition and proof behind it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a regular polygon with interior angle $\theta$ and $n$ sides. The relation
$$\frac{180(n-2)}{n}=\theta$$
holds. Multiplying by $n$ and distributing the 180 yields
$$180n-360=\theta n.$$
Rearranging you obtain
$$180n-\theta n=360.$$
Pulling out the $n$ you get
$$(180-\theta)n=360.$$
Hence, if $\theta$ is your interior angle, then solving for $n$ in
$$(180-\theta)n=0\mod{360}$$
will give you the value of $n$. If you want to work instead with the exterior angle $\theta_{\text{ext}}$ at which you turn then you need to see that $\theta=180-\theta_{\text{ext}}$. Substituting this into the equation above, we get
$$(180-(180-\theta_{\text{ext}}))n=0\mod{360},$$
or
$$\theta_{\text{ext}}n=0\mod{360}.$$
Hence, your trouble seems to be that you are getting the internal angle $\theta$ and the exterior angle $\theta_{\text{ext}}$ confused.

Comment: In the example you mentioned, with turning angle = 60, it results in the tracing out of a hexagon with interior angle = 120. But a hexagon would require 6 steps to return to the starting point, since it has 6 sides. How is the number of steps turning out to be 3?

Comment: @acelixis oh you're right there's another reason let me edit the post.

Comment: @acelixis I got confused because the OP was confusing the internal and exterior angles.

Comment: Ah right. my bad